# How to conditionally set empty column values based on previous columns

Tags: python, pandas

I want to insert values for col 3 as follows:

```
A+ if col 1 is a and col 2 is positive
A- if col 1 is a and col 2 is negative
B+ if col 1 is B and col 2 is positive
B- if col 1 is B and col 2 is negative
```

Data:

```
    COL1  COL2  COL3
0     a    -2
1     a     4
2     b     10
3     b     -8
4     a     10
5     b     5
```

Therefore I want a resulting df of:

```
     COL1  COL2  COL3
0     a    -2      A-
1     a     4      A+
2     b     10     B+
3     b     -8     B-
4     a     10     A+
5     b     5      B+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost a dup for `np.where` as noticed by anky_91:

```
df['COL3'] = df.COL1.str.upper() + np.where(df.COL2.gt(0),'+', '-')
```

gives the expected output:

```
  COL1  COL2 COL3
0    a    -2   A-
1    a     4   A+
2    b    10   B+
3    b    -8   B-
4    a    10   A+
5    b     5   B+
```

Answer (score 0):

This captures the off chance that a `0` means no sign symbol

```
df.COL1.str.upper() + np.sign(df.COL2).map(['', '+', '-'].__getitem__)

0    A-
1    A+
2    B+
3    B-
4    A+
5    B+
dtype: object
```